# Send Picture by socket (send func) in c++ , but do not recive complete(Windows)!

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, send, recv

I am sending data from client to server,But picture do not receive complete.

Client Code:

```
FILE *fr = fopen(tmppicsend, "rb");
char* buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
fread(buffer, size, 1, fr);
send_len_pic = send( m_socket_pic, buffer, size, 0 );
recv( m_socket_pic, rec_end_check, 32, 0 );
fclose(fr);
free(buffer);
```

Server Code:

```
FILE *fw = fopen(fname, "wb");
char* buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
int rec_len = recv( current_client, buffer, size, 0 );
buffer[size]='\0';
fwrite(buffer, size, 1, fw);
size -= size;
free(buffer);
fclose(fw);
```

Config Socket:

```
WSADATA wsaData_pic;
SOCKET m_socket_pic;
SOCKET m_backup_pic;
sockaddr_in con_pic;

 // Initialize Winsock.
int iResult = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData_pic );
if ( iResult != NO_ERROR ){
    //printf("Error at WSAStartup()\n");
}
// Create a socket.
m_socket_pic = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

if ( m_socket_pic == INVALID_SOCKET ) {
    //printf( "Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    //WSACleanup();
}

m_backup_pic = m_socket_pic;

// Connect to a server.
con_pic.sin_family = AF_INET;
con_pic.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( ip );
con_pic.sin_port = htons( 2200 );

if ( connect( m_backup_pic, (SOCKADDR*) &con_pic, sizeof(con_pic) ) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    //printf( "Failed to connect.\n" );
    //WSACleanup();
}else
{   
    m_socket_pic=m_backup_pic;
}


}
```

When I'm comparing this pictures, i see error in sequence number packet(packets do not receive regularly ).
Picture(Pic from Client and Server) were the same size.
I want to send JPEG picture.

Please Help me, tanks.

Comment: `buffer[size]='\0';` is both unnecessary (this is binary data) and undefined because it indexes outside the allocated memory. That means that your server program is invalid.

Comment: I've commented here, but problems remain.

Comment: How do you observe "sequence numbers"? Are you looking at IP packets? If you are, are you aware that IP packets don't necessarily arrive in order but are assembled correctly by the TCP layer? And where do you get `size` from on the server? I think you need to post some more surrounding code.

Comment: I think OS observe sequence number packets.

Comment: I send size of pic file to server. when i receive pic in server and compare size pictures file(in client and server) Pictures were the same size.

Comment: Today, I've tested on Windows 2008(before test i windows 2003), I got better results and fewer photos were corrupted

Comment: You can have both a short send and a short recv, and you should as several answers said only call send with min(64k,sz_left_of_buffer_to_send_sz) and likewise on the recv part.

Comment: @Jonke You cannot have a short `send()` in blocking mode, and there is no need to limit the transfer to 64k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got many attempts to answer.

The best answer for this question is:

Sync client with server for send stream.

because the recv() function i slower than send() function, clients send amount of data that the server is able to receive.

---

**Clients Code:**

```
char* bufferCMP;
bufferCMP = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
p_file = fopen(tmppicsend,"rb");
fread(bufferCMP, 1, size , p_file);
fclose(p_file);


int chunkcount = size / DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
int lastchunksize = size - (chunkcount * DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
int fileoffset=0;

//Sending Actual Chunks
while (chunkcount > 0)
{
    iResult = send( m_socket_pic, bufferCMP + (fileoffset * DEFAULT_BUFLEN) , DEFAULT_BUFLEN , 0 );
    fileoffset++;
    chunkcount--;

    if (iResult != DEFAULT_BUFLEN)
    {
        //printf("Sending Buffer size <> Default buffer length  ::: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        //printf("Sending Buffer size = %d \n", iResult);
    }
}

//Sending last Chunk
iResult = send( m_socket_pic, bufferCMP + (fileoffset * DEFAULT_BUFLEN) , lastchunksize , 0 );
```

---

**Server Code:**

```
int FileCounter=0;
bool flg=true;
char * fileComplete;
char * filesizeBuffer;

FILE *temp;

int iResult;

int receiveBuffer = 0;
int desiredRecBuffer = size ;
//int desiredRecBuffer = DEFAULT_BUFLEN ; 
fileComplete = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)* size );
while (desiredRecBuffer > 0)
{
    iResult = recv( current_client, fileComplete + receiveBuffer , desiredRecBuffer , 0 );
    //iResult = recv( ClientSocket, fileComplete + receiveBuffer , fileSize , 0 );

    if (iResult < 1)
    {
        //printf("Reveive Buffer Error  %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        receiveBuffer += iResult;
        desiredRecBuffer = size - receiveBuffer ;
        //printf("Reveived Data size :  %d \n", iResult);
    }
}

FILE *File = fopen(fname, "wb");
fwrite(fileComplete,1, size , File);
//flg = true;
free(fileComplete);
fclose(File);
```

Comment: There is nothing here that 'syncs client with server for send stream'. What there is, finally, after it had already been pointed out in another answer a month previously, is correct handling of the count returned by `recv()`. There is no truth in the claim that 'the `recv()` function is slower than the `send()` function. The idea doesn't begin to make sense. And how many times are you going to answer your own question?

Answer (score 10):

You are making the usual mistakes. You can't assume that recv() fills the buffer. You have to loop until you have all the data you need, and you have to make use of the count value returned by recv().

Comment: I have implemented this approach but did not answer problem!!

Comment: Client Code: FILE *fr = fopen(tmppicsend, "rb");
while(size > 0)
{
 char buffer_s_p[1024];
 if(size>1024)
 {
  fread(buffer_s_p, 1024, 1, fr);
  send_len_pic+=send( m_socket_pic, buffer_s_p, 1024, 0 );
  size -= 1024;
 } 
 else
 {
  fread(buffer_s_p, size, 1, fr);
  buffer_s_p[size]='\0';
  send_len_pic+=send( m_socket_pic, buffer_s_p, size, 0 );
  size -= size;
 }
 
}
fclose(fr);

Comment: @M.Rezaei Please, the problem is about `recv()` in your server code, not `send()` in your client code...

Comment: @M.Rezaei The code you posted in your comment above does not implement this answer. You have however implemented exactly this in your answer dated October 22 '34 and it *did* fix the problem, according to your own statement.

Answer (score 3):

How do you know the size of the data to receive on the server-side? You should establish some sort of protocol (defined by yourself) between the server and the client. The easiest way is in the first place to send uint64_t (8 bytes) which will hold the picture size, and after that send the data itself. And then after the server reads these first 8 bytes - it will know how much data to expect. Then you just repeat recv() calls until you get all of the data sent by the client. It is a good idea to use `select()` on the server side to wait until the next data portion is available. Btw, if the picture you are trying to send is big enough (and in the most cases it is true), it is sent over the tcp or udp connection part by part, not by a one big piece. And it is unpredictable (the hardware decides it) how big the pieces or how much of them would be sent. So you absolutely should be prepared to repeatedly call recv() to receive all the data the client sends to the server.

Comment: thanks for your answer, But I'm doing all these things.I think the problem is in the Recv() func, because this function is very slow.

Comment: Are you using select() before calling recv()? I can't see it in the code sample you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is the size of data you are sending,
because when you send large packet over network the underlying layers will divide this large packet into small packets and then send those packets over network.

so when you receive these packets the sequence of these packets might change,
thats why you are receiving the same size of data, but the image is not correct.

i will give you a quick solution you can try,

Divide your file into small arrays, lets say each array is 1024 byte, first send the count of these arrays, after that start sending the first array (1024 byte), and then wait for acknowledgement from the other side, repeat until you send all data.

you can do it without acknowledgement, but leave sometime between each send.

Comment: I've used this method, but there are still problems!!

Comment: This is TCP. Reassembly and reordering is taken care of by the protocol. Your answer only makes sense for UDP. -1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert the image buffer to base64, send it to the receiver-part of your code and then un-base and malloc it?

The above way is how our screenshot program work (for remote administration) and it works like a charm..

Comment: I can't see any reason to convert binary data to base64-encoded string representation. The network protocol is supposed to handle binary data well, and the conversion adds more complexity to the program, requires more memory for the additional buffer, more network bandwidth as the base64-encoded version is larger in size than pure binary form, and more CPU time for conversion. But if everything else fails - this can be tried at least for testing if it also gonna fail :)

Answer (score 0):

Client code

```
    /*
     * Send size of the file first.
     */

    n = sizeof(filesize);
    r = send(m_socket_pic, &filesize, n);
    if (r != n) {
        printf("error sending %d bytes\n", n);
    }       

    /*
     * Now send the file.
     */

    n = filesize;
    while (n > 0) {
        r = send(m_socket_pic, buffer, n, 0);
        buffer += r;
        n -= r;    
    }
```

Server code

```
    /*
     * Recv size of the file first.
     */

    n = sizeof(filesize);
    r = recv(current_client, &filefsize, n);
    if (r != n) {
        printf("error receiving %d bytes\n", n);
    }

    /*
     * Now recv the file.
     */

    n = filesize;
    while (n > 0) {
        r = recv(current_client, buffer, n, 0);
        buffer += r;
        n -= r;
    }
```

Comment: I've used this method, but there are still a number of broken photos!!, When I use the "Sleep" in while, I have a better answer.

Comment: This code has the same problem. It assumes that `recv()` fills the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,

The Problem is , Sending large file through sockets.

I have test many ways, But did not answer problem.

It is known,I should use loop for send split data.

The best split size is 512 or 1500, And great problem is in  `recv()` function, This function is very slower than `send()` function.When I use `Sleep(1000)` in loop block, Reduced the number of damaged photos.

Comment: The problem is that you assumed that `recv()` fills the buffer. Adding sleeps into network code is literally a waste of time.